# Changing Wordpress post order with URL string

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a dropdown to sort my custom posts.

I have tried the solutions here - http://ak.net84.net/php/filter-dropdown-for-wordpress/ - and here - http://blog.rutwick.com/use-jquery-to-reorder-your-wp-posts-on-the-fly

I can’t get either of these to work and I can’t even get my posts to sort by adding this to the end of my URL - ?orderby=title&order=DESC.

Out of curiosity, I went over to DigWP and tried this - http://digwp.com/category/admin/?orderby=title&order=DESC which worked and sorts the posts by title and in descending order.
So I am wondering why it won’t work on my site? Here is the code that is getting my posts.

```
<?php   $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                        'post_type' => 'project',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                        ));      
                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the query or perhaps wp_query won't allow ordering posts in this way?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, did you try looking at query_posts(), http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get  the query string variable, i.e. `?orderby=title`

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => get_query_var('orderby'), // will return orderby query string variable
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
));
```

Comment: Brilliant. I thought it was going to be something difficult. Thanks